# Global parameterization of $SO(3, \mathbb R)$ with $3$ real numbers (showing $SO(3)$ is closed).

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, orthogonal-matrices

I'm working on my thesis on the Hopf-Fibration. To discuss the $S^3\rightarrow S^2$ variant, I'm using Quaternions over matrices. During the last review, my advisor said I should probably justify why.

In particular, he said that

> we would *like* to parameterize the $3$-d Manifold $SO(3)$ with $3$ reals, but this is not possible globally.

I on the one hand, $SO(3)$ is in fact $3$ dimensional, as (in matrix representation)

1. the first column $p$ must be of unit length, i.e., from $S^2$
2. the second column must be orthogonal to $p$, and of unit length, i.e., from $S^1$
3. the last column is already determined fully, as the determinant must be $1$.

However, by looking at this argument, we can't find a global parameterization for the first two columns, as $S^2$ and $S^1$ are closed, but $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^1$ are open.

Is there perhaps a more concise argument as to why $SO(3)$ is closed, which would show that the global parameterization with three reals is impossible?

Comment: Why don't you try to write it out more precisely?  Then you should find that both step 1 and step 2 are impossible.  You want to try an easier problem first:  show a circle has no global parameterization.

Comment: @JasonDeVito You put me in a pickle - this was just the argument I intended to use to show that $SO(3)$ is three dimensional $(S^2\times S^1)$

Comment: How do two reals give us a point on $S^2$, *globally*?

Comment: No pickle intended!  And my third sentence was supposed to say "you *may* want..."

Comment: @LeeMosher I was thinking of $(\cos\theta\sin\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta)$, with $\theta\in\mathbb {R} /[0, 2\pi)$, $\phi\in\mathbb{R}/[0, \pi)$ - is the problem just the quotient?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure of your intent in writing "($S^2 \times S^1$)" in that last comment, but at the very least $SO(3)$ is not diffeomorphic to $(S^2 \times S^1)$, as one sees using reasonable simple tools of algebraic topology.

Comment: The problem is that parameterizations are required to have an open domain, an open image, and a smooth inverse.

Comment: So if you wanted the image of a parameterization (of $S^1$, or of $S^2$, or of $SO(3)$) to **not** be a proper subset, i.e. to be the whole space, then you would be asking for the whole space to be diffeomorphic to the domain of the parameterization. Which (for those three examples) may be unwise.

Comment: @LeeMosher I wasn't thinking clearly about what "global parameterization" means, thanks. Is there a more compact/direct argument as to why $S0(3)$ must be closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$SO(3)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^9 = (\mathbb R^3)^3$ because its defining equation $M M^{T} = I$ is a continuous function $\mathbb R^{9} \mapsto \mathbb R^9$ whose image is a closed subset, namely the one point subset $\{I\} \subset \mathbb R^9$.